# Regex Match Within Range

Tags: php, regex

I need do a regex match for ASCII characters 32 - 90 inclusive.

I've attempted the following, however it doesn't seem to return anything.

```
preg_match("/^[\x20-\x5A]+$/u", $input)
```

The idea is that it is from hex `20` to hex `5a`. I pulled these from http://www.asciitable.com/

I've got a spot for testing this on http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2Dh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current range only supports upper case letters, so you need the `/i` modifier:

```
$input = 'adddd ### AAAA????';
preg_match('/^[\x20-\x5A]+$/i', $input); // int(1)
```

Alternatively, add the extra letters in the range:

```
preg_match('/^[\x20-\x5A\x61-\x7A]+$/', $input))
```

Comment: My bad - I forgot the system I was developing for was A-Z not a-z, however I do want to support both.

Comment: Does the `/i` account for a-z also

Comment: @AlexZ Both parts of my answer account for lower case characters.

Comment: Thanks @Jack, the second option seems more readable for future reference, as the `/i` may easily be skipped.

Comment: I notice laravel use https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L1011 the `/u` does this account for uppercase I assume?

Comment: @AlexZ The `/u` allows for assertions such as `\pL\pN` to match characters groups as defined in Unicode.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use preg_match's third parameter to assign it to a variable

`preg_match("/^[\x20-\x5A]+$/u", $input, $matches)`

The [standard return of this function](http://www.php.net/preg_match) is a 1 or 0/FALSE

eg...

```
if(preg_match("/^[\x20-\x5A]+$/u", $input, $matches))
{
  var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4ba0be1a1483fa24d1550df1f6d44179026ae38

Comment: But those are outside of your ASCII range, try it with uppercase `JONES 1234` or change your hexadecimal values to extend it to lower case characters